# GridView RowDataBound For Loop Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a column that looks like this

1
1
5 
1 
1 
1 
5 
1
1
1
2 
1
2 
3 
1 
1 
1 
1 
3

What I want to do highlight everything between 5 and 5 and everything between 2 and 2 etc... However the script below stops after the first section. I want it to loop through all the rows in the grid view.

[code]

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            bool begin = false;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i + 2].Text != "1")
                {
                    row.Cells[i + 2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                    if (!begin) begin = true;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (begin) row.Cells[i + 2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }
```

[/code]

Comment: Why do you even have the first loop ? Also I believe the break is stopping the for each loop from running.

Comment: If I do not have the break it highlights the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

something like this work?

```
 GridViewRow row = e.Row;            
        int firstindex = 0;
        int Lastindex = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;               
            firstindex = value.IndexOf('5');
            Lastindex = value.LastIndexOf('5');
            string refinedVal = value.Substring(0, firstindex);
            string refinedVal1 = value.Substring(firstindex + 1, Lastindex);
            string refinedVal2 = value.Substring(Lastindex);
            string finalop = refinedVal + "<span style='color:blue'>" + refinedVal1 + @"</span>" + refinedVal2;
            row.Cells[0].Text = string.Empty;
            row.Cells[0].Text = finalop;
        }
```

Comment: I got this error: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.

This line --- > string refinedVal = value.Substring(0, firstindex);